# When one can cancel out integration from both sides?

Tags: calculus, statistics

For example, can we go from
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{\Phi^{-1}(w_i)ε_i}P(r_i│ε_i )f(ε_i )dε_i=δ\int_0^\infty f(ε_i )dε_i
$$
to
$$
e^{\Phi^{-1}(w_i)ε_i}P(r_i│ε_i )=δ
$$ 
by cancelling out integration from the both sides? 
Thank you

Comment: It depends on the integrand.

Comment: Can you give me an example? or comment on my example. Here, $f(ε_i)$ is the probability density function of $ε_i$, $ε_i$ can be exponential random variable, $\Phi^{-1}(w_i)$ is the inverse of the normal CDF, $P(r_i│ε_i )$ is an unknown function, and all the remaining parameters are constant. Thank you I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I don't know what $\Phi,P,f$ and $\delta$ are, so I can't comment on your example.

Comment: Here, $f(ε_i)$ is the probability density function of $ε_i$, $ε_i$ can be exponential random variable, $\Phi^{-1}(w_i)$ is the inverse of the normal CDF, $P(r_i│ε_i )$ is an unknown function, and all the remaining parameters are constant. Thank you I appreciate your help :)

Comment: The fact that the "canceling" of the integrals makes the bound variable $\varepsilon_i$ into a free variable is a strong hint that this operation is not valid. Indeed as an exponential variable, $\varepsilon_i$ can take on any value in its range and there is no indication in the original equation that $e^{\Phi^{-1}(w_i)\varepsilon_i}P(r_i\mid\varepsilon_i )$ has the same value for every value of $\varepsilon_i$ as your second equation asserts.

Comment: Almost never. Different functions can have the same integral.

Comment: In fact the "cancelling integration" operation is tantamount to saying, "If the integral of $f$ is finite and the integral of $gf$ is finite, then $g$ is constant." That statement is false, of course.